# How to open only one projects from a Android Studio repository with multiple projects inside

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, google-codelab

I have been facing this problem for a long time, I am following the Compose Codelab and on their github projects they got a lot of android projects into the same repository.

Project structure looks like this:

[image]

How can I only run the BasicLayoutCodelab? I most likely need to Add Configuration, but I did not manage yet, most likely this is a trivial problem, but I have no idea how to fix it.

If needed, the link to the android repository from the android team is [here](https://github.com/android/codelab-android-compose)

Thank you very much!

Comment: You are supposed to just import the project folders separately instead of the repository.

Comment: Just check-out the repository somewhere and then open one of the sub-folder as Project in Android Studio.